# Creating Fictional Slavic Place Names

Tags: vocabulary, geography, slavic, names

I have a very simple question regarding a small problem I cannot find a single satisfying answer to. I am trying to create a country with a prominent Slavic culture. In my story, an alien world has been colonized by the nations of Earth. Respectively, each name their lands and territories how they see fit and in their own language. As for this country, it was colonized by the Slavic nations and is rightly given a Slavic sounding name. In fact, the entire continent it exists on shares the same name.

Now, my problem rests in the fact that I'm American and know little Russian except simple greetings. I want to create a genuine sounding Slavic name for the land but do not know where to start. Honestly, I do not understand the Slavic tongues' structures and vocabularies. I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this question so I'll be blunt. Simply, I want to know how to create a genuine sounding Slavic place name. Particularly, I want a name that describes the land itself (just as Belarus means "White Russia") or named after an important figure (just like how the U.S. state Pennsylvania is named after William Penn).

Comment: I hope you'll name a town Strugatsk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the English Wikipedia does not have an article on Slavic toponymy yet, the best attempt I am able to find is [Bulgarian placename etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_placename_etymology) giving at least some hints. You can find interesting Slavic roots to play with in the article on [Slavic given names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_names).

Additionally, there are some Slavic based conlangs out there, you can honour one of them by employing it in your fictional world, to drop just names [Slovio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovio), [Interslavic](http://steen.free.fr/interslavic), see also [Pan-Slavic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-Slavic_language) for an overview.